# Ssl connection between logstash and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have established ssl connection between logstash and filebeat. It was self explanatory to configure for filebeat as the SSL lines were commented out in filebeat.yml. I just uncommented them and added proper path.

Even for logstash, i could easily find references online for ssl.

But, for elasticsearch and logstash, i am not finding any proper example. Can anyone please help in providing me some example here so that i can refer and try to achieve it

Comment: hi, i have installed x-pack plugin in logstash and kibana. The default username and password for elastic search is "elastic" and "changeme". i have given the same credentials from kibana and logstash to connect to elasticsearch.  But i have an issue here. I am unable to connect to logstash from filebeat. But filebeat to elasticsearch communication is possible. I am able to send logs from filebeat to elasticsearch and i am even able to the view the same in kibana. But i am unable to route the filebeat output through logstash. Can anyone please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: I am working on securing al the connections in ELK. My logstash.conf is as follows. **input { 
 beats
 {
  type => beats
  port => 5044
 }
}

filter { 
  grok {
   match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp} %{IP:FromClient} %{NUMBER:sizeOfFile} This is log level \[%{LOGLEVEL:rollno}\]"}
 }
 
 if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  drop { }
 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
      username => ["elastic"]
      password => ["changeme"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}**

Comment: and filebeat.yml has the following, **output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]**